# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Password Reset Test not passing (error 500)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to figure this issue out for awhile now.  I keep getting the same error and I've re-worked through the code / tried different things to no avail.

This is the failing test:

```
FAIL["test_password_reset", PasswordResetsTest, 4.845783]
 test_password_reset#PasswordResetsTest (4.85s)
        Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <500>
        test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

Here is the test itself:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PasswordResetsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
    @user = users(:esteban)
  end

  test "password_reset" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    # Invalid submission
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # Valid submission
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Get the user from the create action.
    user = assigns(:user)
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select 'div.alert'
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    # Wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input#email[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # Invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user:  { password:              "foobaz",
                   password_confirmation: "barquux" }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # Blank password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user:  { password:              "",
                   password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not_nil flash.now
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    # Valid password & confirmation
    patch_via_redirect password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
                       email: user.email,
                       user: { password:              "foobaz",
                               password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
    assert_template 'users/show'
  end
end
```

I understand what a 500 error code is, I just don't understand *why* I'm getting one, as I've followed the code and it would appear all is well.  I'm also going to post my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                  'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'      =>    'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'     =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact'   =>    'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'    =>    'users#new'
  get 'login'     =>    'sessions#new'
  post 'login'    =>    'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' =>    'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT:  Now I'm getting the following error when I even try to signup for the application:

```
undefined method `send_activation_email' for #<User:0x007faafbdb41f8>
```

Here is the code:

```
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
    @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
     render 'new'
   end
```

Comment: A 500 error means not a problem in the test but in the code. Can you paste the error stack trace of the 500 error (try --trace in the rake test).

Comment: That's a biiiiig test... unit testing is meant for a lot of short test cases, each testing a single scenario. A big test is fine as long as it passes (which is not the interesting case). It becomes a mess when it fails...

Comment: @UriAgassi It's not a unit test, it's an integration test and as such exercises the whole stack for the particular scenario.

Comment: When I do a --trace I don't get the stack trace.

Comment: @estebanrules Are you rescuing the error somewhere in your code?

Comment: @fivedigit No I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

Well after following the error:

```
undefined method `send_activation_email' for #<User:0x007faafbdb41f8>
```

I found that there was a minor error in the code, specifically that I had misspelled `send_activation_email` in the user model.  Thank you for your suggestions.